# What is the fastest way to expand cells content into columns names with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data is in the following format:

```
index                 keys    
1                    key 1
2      key 1\nkey 2\nkey 3
3      key 2\nkey 4\nkey 5
5      key 2\nkey 3\nkey 5
```

The keywords that I am interested in are in the keys column, separated with `\n`. I want to transform each key into a column name and mark with a `True` or `1` the row from where it came, as follows:

```
index                   key 1   key 2   key 3   key 4   key 5
1                       1       0       0       0       0
2                       1       1       1       0       0
3                       0       1       0       1       1
5                       0       1       1       0       1
```

Right now, what I do is that I iterate over the index, save into a dictionary the list of the keys for each row, and then transform re-import it with `pandas.DataFrame.from_dict`, like this:

```
 l=[]
 for i in df.index:
     d={j:True for j in df["keys"][i].split("\n")}    
     l.append(d)
 new_df=pandas.DataFrame(l)
```

It is pretty fast, but since there are a lot of `NaN`, the memory consumption of the dataframe before I convert it to an `int64` type is quite huge. Yet I have dozens of thousands of rows. Does anyone know of a more efficient way of doing it, if possible that would avoid iterating over the rows myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
`str.split` + `stack` + `str.get_dummies` + `groupby` + `sum`:

```
df    
                      keys
index                     
1                    key 1
2      key 1\nkey 2\nkey 3
3      key 2\nkey 4\nkey 5
5      key 2\nkey 3\nkey 5

df['keys'].str.split('\n', expand=True).stack()\
                 .str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum()

       key 1  key 2  key 3  key 4  key 5
index                                   
1          1      0      0      0      0
2          1      1      1      0      0
3          0      1      0      1      1
5          0      1      1      0      1
```

---

**Option 2**
Using `pd.get_dummies`, bypassing `stack`:

```
d = pd.get_dummies(df['keys'].str.split('\n', expand=True))
d.groupby(d.columns.str.split('_').str[1], axis=1).sum()

       key 1  key 2  key 3  key 4  key 5
index                                   
1          1      0      0      0      0
2          1      1      1      0      0
3          0      1      0      1      1
5          0      1      1      0      1
```

---

**Option 3**
Using `stack` + `value_counts` + `unstack`:

```
df['keys'].str.split('\n', expand=True).stack()\
       .groupby(level=0).value_counts().unstack().fillna(0)

       key 1  key 2  key 3  key 4  key 5
index                                   
1        1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
2        1.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    0.0
3        0.0    1.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
5        0.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    1.0
```

Comment: It is indeed the newline character here. I did not know the get_dummies function and am testing your solution. It looks good to me but let's see for the memory consumption side. Thanks !

Comment: @Zero For me, it was r'\\n', but for OP it is just '\n', I think.

Comment: On my example (120 000 rows), the second solution, that bypasses stack, wins in terms of memory consumption and is pretty fast too. Thanks again ! Also @Zero : I'm using python3

Comment: @baloo I've found an option 3. If you decide to benchmark, let me know how you find it.

Comment: Memory error for option 3. The big advantage of option 2 is that 0s are not upgraded to floats, while in option 3 unstack creates NaNs and this forces the dataframe to upgrade to floats.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way with comprehensions

```
In [5442]: pd.DataFrame([{k:1 for k in x.split('\\n')} for x in df['keys']]).fillna(0)
Out[5442]:
   key 1  key 2  key 3  key 4  key 5
0    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
1    1.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    0.0
2    0.0    1.0    0.0    1.0    1.0
3    0.0    1.0    1.0    0.0    1.0
```

Another way using `apply`, which would be slower on larger data

```
In [5429]: df['keys'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({k:1 for k in x.split('\\n')})
                           ).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[5429]:
   key 1  key 2  key 3  key 4  key 5
0      1      0      0      0      0
1      1      1      1      0      0
2      0      1      0      1      1
3      0      1      1      0      1
```

---

Timings

```
In [5447]: dff.shape
Out[5447]: (20000, 2)

In [5444]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([{k: 1for k in x.split('\\n')} for x in dff['keys']]).fillna(0)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.6 ms per loop

In [5445]: %timeit dff['keys'].str.split(r'\\n', expand=True).stack().str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum()
1 loop, best of 3: 399 ms per loop

In [5446]: %%timeit
      ...: d = pd.get_dummies(dff['keys'].str.split(r'\\n', expand=True))
      ...: d.groupby(d.columns.str.split('_').str[1], axis=1).sum()
1 loop, best of 3: 62.0 ms per loop
```

Comment: That's a vectorized way of doing what I already did. It's quite fast as you show but the problem is that the memory consumption surges because of int64 promotion to float64 because of all the NaNs. Thanks for your help though !